# How to use SVNKit to get the list of all revisions merged from one branch to another?

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

#### Purpose:

As a quality check, we need to make sure that all qualified revisions are merged up to all higher revisions.

#### Example:

`Release_10 --> Release_11`

In TortoiseSVN, it is very easy to figure out which revisions have been merged by clicking the "Show Log" button. Merged revisions are clearly distinguished by formatting and a merge icon.

You can also list all merged revisions through pure SVN:

```
C:\Release_11>svn mergeinfo --show-revs merged https://svn_repo/project/branches/releases/Release_10
r32894
r32897
r32901
r32903
r32929
r32987
r32994
r32996
r33006
r33017
r33020
r33021
r33041
r33045
r33077
```

Currently, I have the code that lists all revision info:

```java
SVNURL svnURL = SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url);
SVNRepository repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(svnURL);
BasicAuthenticationManager authManager = BasicAuthenticationManager.newInstance("username", "password".toCharArray());
authManager.setProxy("00.00.00.00", 8080, null, (char[])null);
repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Collection<SVNLogEntry> logEntries = repository.log(new String[] { "" }, null, 0, -1, true, true);
```

Now I just need to figure out which ones have been merged.

#### Preferences:

1. A single call to the repo to get all merged revisions. (Or better yet: A single call to get all the revisions and whether or not they were merged.)
2. Would prefer not to have a local checkout of the SVN repo.

#### Notes:

- Using SVNKIT v1.8.14, but am not locked into a specific revision.

Comment: Which version of svnkit are you using?

Comment: SVNKIT: v1.8.14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run [`svn mergeinfo`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.mergeinfo.html) with absolute URLs for both source and target, you won't need a local checkout of the repository:

```bash
svn mergeinfo --show-revs merged https://svn_repo/project/branches/releases/Release_10 https://svn_repo/project/branches/releases/Release_11
```

To run this command, on SVNKit 1.7 or later, you can use [`SvnLogMergeInfo`](https://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc2/SvnLogMergeInfo.html):

```
SvnOperationFactory svnOperationFactory = new SvnOperationFactory();
try {
    String repo = "https://svn_repo/project/branches/releases/";
    String srcBranch = repo + "Release_10";
    String dstBranch = repo + "Release_11";

    // svnOperationFactory.setAuthenticationManager(null);

    SvnLogMergeInfo op = svnOperationFactory.createLogMergeInfo();
    op.setFindMerged(true); // --show-revs merged
    op.setSource(SvnTarget.fromURL(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(srcBranch)));
    op.setSingleTarget(SvnTarget.fromURL(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(dstBranch)));
    op.setReceiver(new ISvnObjectReceiver<SVNLogEntry>() {

        @Override
        public void receive(SvnTarget target, SVNLogEntry logEntry) throws SVNException {
            System.out.println("------\n" + logEntry);
        }

    });
    op.run();
} finally {
    svnOperationFactory.dispose();
}
```

For older versions, you can use [`SVNDiffClient.doGetLogMergedMergeInfo`](https://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/SVNDiffClient.html#doGetLogMergedMergeInfo(org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNURL,%20org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNRevision,%20org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNURL,%20org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNRevision,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String[],%20org.tmatesoft.svn.core.ISVNLogEntryHandler)).

Comment: This method takes quite a bit of time for me since it doesn't stop on copy/rename. I didn't see an option to make this stop looking past the end of the branch. Is there one?

Comment: @ScrappyDev It doesn't look like `svn mergeinfo` has that option. Would you rather use `--show-revs eligible`? Then you can check if there are revisions on release_10 not yet merged to release_11, which might be faster.

Comment: I have another possible solution that may be faster using the "showMergedRevisions" flag. However, your solution almost works. If you change `op.setFindMerged(false)` to `op.setFindMerged(true)`, that will act like `--show-revs merged`.

Comment: @ScrappyDev Good catch, I have it backwards. The doc says: "true if should report merged revisions, false if should report eligible for merge."

Comment: I edited that part of your answer and made your answer the solution. Thanks!!