# How to Get a Log Between Two Branches Using SvnKit?

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I have a branch structure like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GCWX.jpg).
How can I get an svn log between two revisions in *different* branches using SvnKit (for example, a revision from branch **5A.1** and a revision from branch **2B.3**), excluding already merged revisions?
I know, how to do it inside *single* branch using SvnLog operation:

```
// factory - SvnOperationFactory instance
SvnLog svnLog = factory.createLog();
// target - SvnTarget instance, created from branch URL
// using SvnTarget.fromURL(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(branchPath))
// my problem is there: how to tell svnLog that I need a diffrence 
// between two different branches?
// Adding a second target won't solve my problem, I suppose
svnLog.addTarget(target);
// if you need to go deeper in history, set to "false"
// if you looking for revisions only inside this branch, set to "true" 
svnLog.setStopOnCopy(stopOnCopy);
// if you need to include merged revisions too
svnLog.setUseMergeHistory(useMergeHistory);
SVNRevision startRev = SVNRevision.create(startRevNumber);
SVNRevision endRev = SVNRevision.create(startRevNumber);
svnLog.addRange(SvnRevisionRange.create(startRev, endRev));
// the limit of SvnLogEntry items
svnLog.setLimit(limit);
return svnLog.run(null);
```

There is some kind of misunderstanding that I can't handle with.
SvnKit version is 1.8.7

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you should use `SvnLogMergeInfo`. Check out this solution:

[How to use SVNKit to get the list of all revisions merged from one branch to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510040/how-to-use-svnkit-to-get-the-list-of-all-revisions-merged-from-one-branch-to-ano)